# How to Findout if a neural network is invariant

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

In object recognition, translating an image by a few pixels in some direction
should not affect the category recognized. Suppose we consider images with an object in the
foreground on top of a uniform background. Suppose also that the objects of interest are always at least 10 pixels away from the image's borders. Is the following neural network
invariant to translations of at most 10 pixels in some direction?

a) Neural network with two hidden layers consisting of convolutions (5x5 patches with a stride of 1 in each direction) followed by max pooling (4x4 patches with a stride of 4 in each direction) and a softmax output layer.

Here the translation is applied only to the foreground object while keeping the background fixed.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of neural network are you using?

It could be invariant if the initial weights are always the same, but some NN can also have stochastic inner mechanisms (ex, noise and minibatches).

In all cases, you can use the same random root number to always find the same result.

If you use CNNs, you can run them in a deterministic way. It requires some setups.

For example:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html

Comment: I am Using Convolutional Neural Network

Comment: I have updated my answer.